# Fragment Layout not corresponding to preview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

So, first of all I'm very new to Android so this may be a very dumb question, but..

I have in my mainActivity layout a viewPager which calls some fragments of different type (I have made 4-5 xml layout displaying different informations)

Despite I created all the layout basing on weighed LinearLayout to maximize compatibility, in the preview the visibility seems perfect in each device I selected, but once I load the application on my phone, the layout has bizarre behavior.

Here an example (preview vs. screenshot from my device)

[image]

I'm not sure about where I made the mistake, I would like to know:

1) What happened

2) What cause this behaviour

3) How to fix it (a link with a guide would be very welcome)

Thanks very much!

Comment: do you have same dimensions for the preview and your real device?

Comment: from what I see in your screen shots, the dimensions of the preview and device are not the same. Thus, I suggest you study "supporting multiple dimensions of devices", try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713695/how-do-native-apps-pull-off-being-responsive/35713838#35713838

Comment: Post your `layout xml` file.

Comment: both preview and my device are 1080x1920!